# Подключение к серверу NodeJS/Express через OpenVPN сеть

Tags: windows, openvpn

Имею:
Статический IP, wi - fi роутер, сервер с OS Windows 10 и OpenVPN Server, клиента с OS Android  и OpenVPN Connect (интернет идет через мобильную связь, для понимания).
На сервере включен OpenVPN Server с такой конфигурацией:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\server.key"  # This file should be kept secret
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ta.key" 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-GCM
persist-key
persist-tun
status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\status.log"
log         "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 4
mute 20
windows-driver wintun
```

На клиенте включен OpenVPN Connect с такой конфигурацией:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote {АДРЕС СЕРВЕРА(использую статический IP)} 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-GCM
verb 0
connect-retry-max 25
```

В настройках роутера пробросил порт 1194 на ip адрес 192.168.1.3 и порт 1194 - адрес сервера в пределах роутера.
Подключается успешно, в логах сервера появляется каждый раз клиент при переподключение оного.
Теперь, на сервере я написал тестовое приложение NodeJS + Express, которое развёрнуто на том же сервере без домена, ssl и прочего (всего лишь тест). Подключаюсь так:

```
192.168.1.3:3000/config_cpu
192.168.1.3 - ip адрес сервера в пределах роутера
3000 - порт, на котором крутится приложение
```

В пределах wi-fi сети я подключаюсь к серверному приложению без проблем.
Теперь я хотел осуществить то, ради чего вопрос: я пытаюсь подключиться к серверному приложению с клиента вне wi-fi сети, то есть через VPN тоннель (OpenVPN), однако всегда получаю timeout. На клиенте (OS Android) установлен Termux, с помощью него и пробую. Как пытаюсь делать подключение:

```
curl -X POST {АДРЕС СЕРВЕРА(использую статический IP)}:3000/config_cpu
```

Подскажите, где я что-то упускаю или что-то понял не верно?

P.S.: есть подозрения по поводу порта 3000, ведь мне доступен только 1194, но развернуть клиентское приложение на этом порту не могу, так как он занят OpenVPN Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыл добавить маршрут из туннельной сети в локальную.

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Теперь всё работает.